# How can I navigate from one Stack to another Stack?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using the latest version of React native. I need to navigate from one Stack .Navigator to another Stack.Navigator.

The structure would be the following:

-Stack.Navigator (LoginStack)

1. -Stack Screen -> LoginScreen
2. -Stack.Screen -> CreateAccount

-Stack.Navigator (ProdsStack)

1. -Stack.Screen -> ProdsScreen
2. -Stack.Screen -> DetailsScreen

I need to navigate from LoginScreen to ProdsScreen, I've tried Navigation.navigate but it doesn't give me any results.

**This is the code for my router:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import LoginStack from './src/components/Login/LoginStack';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import ListProdsStack from './src/components/ListProds/ListProdsStack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MainTabScreen() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="ProdListTab" component={ListProdsStack} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="LoginStack"
          component={LoginStack}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ProdListStack"
          component={MainTabScreen}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**This is my LoginStack**

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const LoginStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#F2F302',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#3C2B58',
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Login Screen"
        component={LoginScreen}
        options={{headerShown: false}}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="Cuenta Nueva" component={CreateAccount} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

**This is my ListProfsStack:**

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const ListProdsStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="ProdList" component={ListProdsScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

I was thinking of using different Stacks because each Tab has its own screens which cannot be accessed from one Stack to another Stack directly.

Comment: As suggested in https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#best-practices-when-nesting, for your specific scenario, you should unload login stack and load prod stack on successfull login.

Comment: As I see the example of the page you sent me, my code is similar to the one seen there, however, I don't know how to navigate between those screens and in that link, it doesn't show how to do it.